# How to make an embedded google groups frame redirect back to the website after login?

Tags: javascript, html, frame, google-groups

I have embedded a [google groups instance in my website](http://democracy.foundation/discussion-group/) using this frame:

```
<iframe id="forum_embed"
  src="javascript:void(0)"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  width="900"
  height="700">
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('forum_embed').src =
     'https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/democracyfoundation'
     + '&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=false'
     + '&parenturl=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
</script>
```

After the user logs in to google to make a new post, he is redirected to a blank page and not back the website. How can I make it so that it redirects them back to the google groups frame in the website?